# Writing a boolean on a specific offset inside a file

Tags: java, boolean, offset, objectoutputstream

I'm currently trying to make a very fast application that can write data to a file very quickly. However, the only way to do this is if I'm able to access a specific offset inside a file and write a `boolean` there.

First of all, I'm assuming that `ObjectOutputStream(FileOutputStream)` always writes data to the file the same way, keeping the same structure for the data.

Secondly, what I need to do is to access a specific offset of a `boolean` inside a `boolean[][]` inside the file. Is there any Java class that "scrolls" through the data structure created inside a file by OOS?

If not, maybe someone can shed some light on how to do this very fast or on how to do this ensuring the file does not get corrupted (hence the data not getting corrupted).

Comment: Define "very fast".  The slowest part of any file access (assuming disk media) is going to be latency waiting for the platter to spin to the data.  As to ensuring the file does not get corrupted, that's up to you writing the code correctly. Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Well, very fast I admit is unclear, but I'm looking for something that is faster than re-writing the whole structure through OOS. The problem with data corruption is that I currently do exactly this (re-write the data) and if the process crashes in the middle, the file might be corrupted, whereas by writing the boolean, if there would be a crash I would either get it written or not (not sure about what I'm saying).